# Requestsでjsonのデコードの仕方がわかりません

Tags: python, python-requests

以下のプログラムを実行するとエラーが出ます。

```
"TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable"
```

これはJSON化していないことが原因でしょうか？
JSON化するにしても `res.json` と `res.text` のどちらがいいのかわかりません。

```
import requests
import json

#郵便番号取得
class Address:

    def __init__ (self,zipcode):
    
        self.zipcode=zipcode

    def get_address(self):
        url="https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search"
        params={"zipcode":self.zipcode}

        res=requests.get(url,params=params)
       # print(res.text)
        
        results=res["results"]
        address=results[0]  #物によっては複数返ってくることがある
        print(f"住所:{address['zipcode']}{address['address1']}{address['address2']}{address['address3']}")  

add=Address("5670031")
result=add.get_address()

print(result)
```

Comment: Python であればどこでエラーが起きたかも出力されているはずなので、エラーを省略せずに全てコピー＆ペーストするよう [edit] していただけると回答しやすくて嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` は https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ でしょうか?

そうであれば、`requests.get()` の戻り値は[Response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response)型なので、`res["results"]` というアクセスはできません。ご察しのとおり、`json()` を呼べばよいでしょう。

```
  results = res.json()["results"]
```